# Viewing source in XML to XHTML transformation through XSL

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt, xhtml

I'm trying to use an XSL file to transform an XML file into an XHTML file. How can I view the XHTML source that is output after the transformation. I'm currently viewing the results through Firefox, but all I see is the rendered version of the XHTML file. I want to see the source, but when I go to View->Page Source, all I see is the XML. I'm running Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!

-- Corey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60), and utilize its View Generated Source option.

From the context menu choose Web Developer --> View Source --> View generated source.

Here's a link to a [w3school's XSL sample page](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/cdcatalog_with_xsl.xml) if anyone wants to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the transform on the command line and then point firefox at the generated file until you have the XHTML correct.

The command you need would be something like:

```
xsltproc -o xshtmlfile.html xslfile.xsl xmlfile.xml
```

You may need to install libxslt to get the xsltproc command.

Comment: I would also use the 'view generated source' tool mentioned in RichardOD's answer sometimes.

Comment: When would you choose to use the 'view generated source' tool as opposed to the method you described?

Comment: To be honest 'view generated source' is the better choice most of the time when you are producing xhtml. My first solution sprung to mind because I produce other output formats (eg XSL-FO or SVG) more often.